# range on multiple columns in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

My table :

```
CREATE TABLE user_position (
  geopart text, // first 3 characters of geohash
  geohash text,
  datetime timestamp,
  userId bigint,
  PRIMARY KEY ((geopart), geohash, datetime, user_id)
);
```

My dummy query :

```
select * from user_position where geopart = 'abc' and geohash > 'a' and geohash < 'z' and datetime >= '2015-08-08 15:08:58+0530';
```

Error:

```
Bad Request: PRIMARY KEY column "datetime" cannot be restricted (preceding column "geohash" is restricted by a non-EQ relation)
```

Question:

What I am doing wrong? If range on multiple columns is not possible in Cassandra then how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cassandra is quite restrictive when it comes to querying, in that it is not general purpose like a RDBMS. You cannot perform a range query on multiple columns in Cassandra. The following rules also apply:

- If not doing a select all, you will need to provide the partition key so Cassandra can find the node with the data you're looking for
- You can only filter on columns which are in the primary key (partition key and clustering columns)
- The order of the columns in the primary key definition is important -- this is how Cassandra still store the data on disk
- You can only filter on a clustering column if the 'previous' column is also filtered (in the order of the primary key definition)
- Once you perform a range query, you cannot further filter on a subsequent clustering column

All of these rules are there to avoid people running anti-patterns within Cassandra.

One option you have to perform a range query on multiple columns and to have a more robust method of retrieving your data is to integrate with a search platform such as Solr.

Comment: can I put a `IN` query after a range query?

Comment: Nope, once you filter using a range on one of your columns in Cassandra, you can't even use an = filter on a subsequent clustering column.